# Ping Pong Math node - what does it do?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

Reading through the [math node docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/math.html), I came across a math function named "ping-pong".

The docs state that ping-pong does the following

> The output value is moved between 0.0 and the Scale based on the input value.

What in the world does that mean?  Can anyone tell me what the actual ping-pong function is?  What input values lead to an output of 0, and what input values lead to an output of "scale"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a positive symmetrical triangle-wave, amplitude *Scale*, period  2 * *Scale*, 0 at 0.

[image]

Here's the function illustrated with 'Scale' (from the bottom up) set to 1, 0.5, and 0.333.

These planes are 8 units across, and 2 up, 0 at center.

You could roll your own like this:

```
PingPong(Value) = Scale - abs( (abs(Value) % (2*Scale)) - Scale)
```

..but someone else might come up with a neater way.. :)

**edit:** Indeed they have :) thanks to @Nikolai for:

```
Scale - abs(Value % (2*Scale) - Scale )
```

You could wrap up the node like this to give more intuitive inputs?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: great illustrative answer, thank you.  Glad I asked, because that's not at all what I imagined it would be.  I expected a square-wave type function.

Comment: @rothloup Thanks!  .. Keep the graphing trick in your back pocket.. you can visualise the other functions, and your own combinations.

Comment: > ..but someone else might come up with a neater way.. :)

You can remove the inner abs:

Start with abs(input), then flip it with a negative sign: `-abs(input)`

Then add scale to move it up: `scale - abs(input)`

Then get it in range: `scale - abs(input%2*scale)`

Finally shift the peak so that it sits at scale: `scale - abs(input%(2*scale)-scale)`

Comment: @Nickolai hehe .. I love it when that happens :) Will insert with a credit, and leave the challenge up, when tested.