# How to get Mirrored-Repeat texture extension / UV in 2.8

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, import

I've imported a model from a game. It has UVs stretching beyond the image texture included. The texture is designed where the UV maps to a mirrored-repeating texture, but Blender 2.8 only has a "Repeat" texture extension.

This has been solved in the past for an older version of Blender, but the solution given does not apply to Blender 2.8: [How to repeat a texture mirrored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/how-to-repeat-a-texture-mirrored)

[image: Example UV with object result and texture settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest, with a UV map like this:

[image]

.. which I think is equivalent to yours?

Then all you have to do is put a *Math > Ping-Pong* node in the way of the X and Y outputs of the UV texture space, on the way into the image:

[image]

If you find you need to tweak offsets, scales of the repeat, you may find it easier to wrap *Ping-Pong* up with something like the 'Triangle Wave' group you can download from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/186123/35559).

If you have several different UV maps, then instead of the *Texture Coordinate* input node, you would use a *UV Map* input node, to select the right one.